# Places API returning different precisions for lat and long

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm having some difficulty dealing with precision regarding lat and long coordinates, the way the are recorded in the database and returned from Google. I can't seem to match them.

I have the code below to get a location from Places autocomplete and I noticed it's giving me weird results. The lat precision is always much smaller than long, which makes it difficult for me to round them to "6", which is the one I'm using in my database.

```
    placesAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(autocompleteInput, autocompleteOptions);
placesAutocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
google.maps.event.addListener(placesAutocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var loc = placesAutocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location;
    console.log('lat='+loc.lat()+', long='+loc.lng());
    createMarker({ map: map, position:loc, draggable: true });
    map.setCenter(loc);
});
```

This prints `lat=-22.938508, long=-43.17830300000003`

The other events on the map (such as double-click to create a marker) works fine and give identical precisions.

Comment: When the lat gets inserted in mysql, it gets rounded down to -22,938507. I'd like to try to have both coords in higher precision so I could control the rounding down myself across the app and database. But I can't since it's already rounded down to 6.

Comment: Why is that a problem? The 6th decimal place is less that .2 m [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees)

Comment: I need to match them, to check for duplicity. Can't have two markers on the same coordinates. I'm having trouble finding exact duplicates because of these tiny differences in precision and rounding. Any ideas?

Comment: why can't you have multiple markers at the same coordinates(imagine how many places may exist in a skyscraper, all at the same location but all are different). When you want to avoid duplicates use the `placeId`. However, it's not allowed to store these data at all.

Comment: In my specific scenario it is not good to have many markers in one place. Nearby is ok, but on on top of the other (even using clusters) makes navigation very complicated. I'd rather ask the user to move his marker a little.

Comment: Calculate the distance between the coordinates, if it is less than 1 meter (or 0.5 meter, owr whatever you like), they are at the same location.

Comment: I found a "solution", which is to round up the 6th digit. But still, isn't it weird that Places returns such different precisions to the coordinates?